# Unexpected scala.MatchError

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a method with the following definition :

```
def userPosts(userId: String): Future[List[Post]]
```

I would like to have a method which returns cached date or calls `userPosts` if there is no cached data. I've prepared something like this:

```
def cachedUserPosts(userId: String): Future[List[Post]] = {
    for {
        cached <- bucket.get[List[Post]]("posts_" + userId)
    } yield {
        cached match {
            case Some(list) => list
            case None => userPosts(userId) match {
                 case list:List[Post] => list
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have an error:

```
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: scala.MatchError: scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@23cf4a0c (of class scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise)

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[MatchError: scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@23cf4a0c (of class scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise)]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.11-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.11-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library-2.11.2.jar:na]
Caused by: scala.MatchError: scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@23cf4a0c (of class scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise)
    at models.Post$$anonfun$fastUserPosts$1.apply(Post.scala:130) ~[classes/:na]
    at models.Post$$anonfun$fastUserPosts$1.apply(Post.scala:126) ~[classes/:na]
    at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:236) ~[scala-library-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191) ~[scala-library-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:236) ~[scala-library-2.11.2.jar:na]
2015-07-26 19:33:24.211 INFO net.spy.memcached.auth.AuthThread:  Authenticated to 192.168.10.42/192.168.10.42:11210
```

Do you have any idea what's going on?

Comment: What is the type of `bucket.get[List[Post]]("posts_" + userId)` ? `Future[Option[List[Post]]]` ??

Comment: Yes, it is Future[Option[List[Post]]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pattern matching on a `Future`, if we try an analogous pattern match in the console :

```
val p = Promise[Int]
val f = p.future
p.success(5) // fulfill the promise
```

Pattern matching on `f` gives us :

```
scala> f match { case i: Int => i }
<console>:15: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : Int
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[Int]
              f match { case i: Int => i }
                                ^
```

Your `userPosts` function returns a `Future[List[Post]]` and you can't pattern match on the future directly to get the `List[Post]`. You can find more information on working with [`Future`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future) on the [Scala website](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).

Lets fix your `cachedUserPosts` function. Your version could also be written as (*does not compile*):

```
bucket.get[List[Post]]("posts_" + userId) map ( cached => cached match {
  // List[Post] in Future.map => Future[List[Post]]
  case Some(list) => list
  // userPosts already gives us a Future[List[Post]]
  // We could have used Await.result(userPosts(userId), 5.seconds)
  // to get the List[Post] from the Future, but then we would be blocking
  case None => userPosts(userId)
})
```

If we convert the `map` into a `flatMap` we can return a `Future[List[Post]]`, but then we would also need to return a `Future[List[Post]]` in the `Some` case, which can easily be done using `Future.successful` :

```
bucket.get[List[Post]]("posts_" + userId) flatMap ( cached => cached match {
  // List[Post] to Future[List[Post]] using Future.successful
  case Some(list) => Future.successful(list)
  case None => userPosts(userId)
})
```

We could clean this up a little bit, by using `map`/`getOrElse` instead of pattern matching on the `Option` :

```
def cachedUserPosts(userId: String): Future[List[Post]] =
  bucket.get[List[Post]]("posts_" + userId).flatMap { cached =>
     cached.map(list => Future.successful(list))
           .getOrElse(userPosts(userId))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! That is what I was looking for.